# Como passar um parâmetro GET em uma URL no Angular 4+ ? Usando o sistema de rotas

Tags: angular, get, angular2-http

Estou precisando inserir um parâmetro **GET** depois de entrar na página com a URL.

Por exemplo:

Cliquei aqui x fui para a página y.
http://exemplo/paginay**?=parametroGet**

O **parâmetro GET** será um ID, passado ao clicar em um botão que muda a rota atual.

Comment: Da uma olhada na documentação pra query params https://angular.io/guide/router#query-parameters-and-fragments

Comment: ou se o parâmetro for mandatório https://angular.io/guide/router#route-definition-with-a-parameter

Comment: @EduardoVargas eu consegui fazer, coloquei a resposta ai em baixo, eu ainda não conhecia a sintaxe direito, mas da pra fazer o que eu queria com o queryParams e depois usar um comando especifico para pegar esse get na url, obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Atualização do modo encontrado:

```
<a class="icon-plus-details" [routerLink]="['/', linkDetail]" [queryParams]="{id: ownerId}"></a>
```

Esse

```
[queryParams]="{id: ownerId}"
```

Insere na *url* retornada um **parâmetro** *get*: url_exemplo?id=12 por exemplo.

Depois disso, é utilizada a forma do **router** capturar um valor *get* presente em uma *url* atual.
Dentro do componente que é resultado da **rota selecionada**, é feito da seguinte forma:

Realiza todos *imports* necessários e etc do **RouterParam**, e depois pode ser retornada em uma variável através da sintaxe abaixo presente em **const id**

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

getParam() {
const id = this.routerParam.snapshot.queryParams['id'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No Template

```
New Exercise
```

Request:

```
  
this.route.queryParams
    .filter(params => params.id)
    .subscribe(params => { this.id = params.id;});
```

Comment: Além do código, você poderia explicar para o autor da pergunta qual a proposta dessas linhas de código!